# React Native Audio Manipulation (trim and combine with timing)

Tags: react-native, audio

Is there a package that works for trimming and combining user uploaded audio? I also need to be able to record audio but I figure that that is probably a separate package haha.

Basically the user in my app would be able to upload two audio files and they should be able to trim down both of the, with something similar to https://github.com/repodio/react-native-trimmer but also be able to to combine the two audio tracks together into one with fade if possible.

All the packages I've found seem to be old and no longer maintained or only for iOS (https://github.com/thehanimo/react-native-audiokit)